# Добавление и удаление ячеек через JS

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо сделать скрипт который при нажатии на кнопку создаёт ячейку таблицы в низ, и при нажатии на другую кнопку создаёт ячейки таблицы в право. И ещё 2 кнопки которые так же удаляют ячейки. Удалось разобраться только в создании ячеек в низ. Буду рад любой подсказке. Заранее благодарен!

```js
function addStr() {
  var str = document.getElementById('tableResult');
  var add = str.insertRow(-1);
  var addTr = document.createElement("tr");
  var addTd = document.createElement("td");
  addTd.innerHTML = "test";
  addTr.appendChild(addTd);
  str.appendChild(addTr);
}

function deleteRow() {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addStr()">Добавить ячейку в низ</button>
<button onclick="addStr()">Добавить строку в право</button>
<button onclick="addStr()">Удалить строку в лево</button>
<button onclick="deleteRow()">Удалить ячейку на верх</button>
<table id="tableResult" style="border:1px solid;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var table = document.getElementById('tableResult');
var row;
addRow();

function addRow() {
  row = table.insertRow();
  addCol();
}

function addCol() {
  var col = document.createElement("td");
  col.innerHTML = "test";
  row.appendChild(col);
}

function deleteRow() {
  table.deleteRow(table.rows.length - 1);
  row = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
}

function deleteCol() {
  var cols = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
  if (cols.length > 1) {
    row.removeChild(cols[cols.length - 1]);
  } else {
    deleteRow();
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addRow()">Добавить ячейку в низ</button>
<button onclick="addCol()">Добавить строку в право</button>
<button onclick="deleteCol()">Удалить строку в лево</button>
<button onclick="deleteRow()">Удалить ячейку на верх</button>
<table id="tableResult" style="border:1px solid;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!